# Posting form values to DB using kendoUI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Not able to save records to DB

I have tried different ways of passing the values to model, even hard coded values.

---

MODEL:

```
public class RaarrInspectionModel : BaseModel
{
    public int InspectionTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ProcedureId { get; set; }
    public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
    public int ResultId { get; set; }
    public int RaarrEquipmentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InspectionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextInspectionDue { get; set; }
    public int InspectorId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool ReadManufacturerInfo { get; set; }
    public bool RecomendedLifespan { get; set; }
    public bool LoadLimitCheck { get; set; }
    public bool VisualTactileCheck { get; set; }
    public bool FuntionChecks { get; set; }
    }
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
public class RaarrInspectionVm : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int InspectionTypeId { get; set; }

    public int ProcedureId { get; set; }

    public int SpecificationId { get; set; }

    public int? RaarrEquipmentId { get; set; }

    public int ResultId { get; set; }

    public DateTime InspectionDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime NextInspectionDue { get; set; }
    public int InspectorId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public bool ReadManufacturerInfo { get; set; }

    public bool RecomendedLifespan { get; set; }

    public bool LoadLimitCheck { get; set; }

    public bool VisualTactileCheck { get; set; }

    public bool FuntionChecks { get; set; }
}
```

the view is very simple using kendo d-down lists and check boxes

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Inspect()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult Inspect(RaarrInspectionVm vm)
    {

        var model = vm.ToModel(new RaarrInspectionModel());
        var raarrInspectionEf = new RaarrInspectionEf();
        raarrInspectionEf.Upsert(model);

        return RedirectToAction("Equipment");
    }
```

ENTITY FRAMEWORK CLASS:

```
public RaarrInspection Upsert(RaarrInspectionModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            return model.Id.ValidId() ? Update(model) : Add(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            new LogError(false, "Code RaarrEquipment", 
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), Environment.UserName, ex, 
model).LogToEventLog();
            return null;}}
private RaarrInspection Add(RaarrInspectionModel model)
    {var c = model.ToDomain(new RaarrInspection());
        _db.RaarrInspection.Add(c);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return c;}
```

Expect the records to be saved to the database. Application doesn't crash.

Comment: Show your `RaarrInspectionEf` code since you say it is not saving. Also confirm `vm` has expected data at that point.

Comment: public RaarrInspection Upsert(RaarrInspectionModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                return model.Id.ValidId() ? Update(model) : Add(model);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                new LogError(false, "Code RaarrEquipment", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), Environment.UserName, ex, model).LogToEventLog();
                return null;}}
private RaarrInspection Add(RaarrInspectionModel model)
        {var c = model.ToDomain(new RaarrInspection());
            _db.RaarrInspection.Add(c);
            _db.SaveChanges();
     return c;}

Comment: If you are not getting an error or exception and you are hitting the Add or Update with values, then I would look at connection string issues. You may be updating a different database.

Comment: Update: this issue was caused due to removing a not null property in the front end so model state was invalid